# RDLC Bar chart - Only integer intervals in Values axis

Tags: rdlc, bar-chart

I'm trying to fix a RDLC report chart to show only integer intervals in Y axis (values axis).

The problem is, as soon as values get small, like [1, 2, 4, ...], the axis intervals starts showing decimal values between the whole ones (i.e. it goes [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, etc.]). Values them selves are calculated as count(x), so it always is an integer value. How can I remove the decimal intervals in the values axis labels?

The report is defined and edited through Visual Studio 2012 native report editor tool and/or XML definition. So I would love to see how it can be changed through that tool or straight up XML properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that it is possible to right-click the axis and assign properties to it. But in the end, it seems it isn't possible to achieve what I need through these tools, while keeping the intervals relative to the maximum value. I would have to count the interval externally in the code and pass it as a parameter. Otherwise - no matter what, as soon as the numbers get small enough (with max value at ~ 3-5), the decimals appear.